How can I perform functional unit tests in .net Aspire?
How do I perform functional unit tests of a project which relies on resources managed by .net Aspire, i. e. how do I test a service in a project that requires a Postgres DB? During "normal operation", Aspire spins up the container with the DB and injects a connection string into the dependent project. But for unit tests, DistributedApplicationTestingBuilder is used, which does not yield a handle to the services defined in the project-under-test.
One could setup all dependencies using docker-compose or a similar tool, but this is countering the conveniences of using .net Aspire.
Below I answer my question because it was not such a trivial task to solve and maybe it is helpful to somebody else before it (hopefully) get integrated in the Aspire code base.

You can find a working example here.
To do functional unit tests, build your test from this custom WebApplicationFactory:
/// <summary>
/// Custom WebApplicationFactory for the UnitTestsInAspire.Web project. It spins up the AppHost and injects the environmental 
/// variables from the project (webfrontend). To adapt it for other projects, you need to change the name of the
/// AppHost project, of the required dependencies to spin up and the project's designation defined in the AppHost; see (§§).
/// </summary>
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    // holds the AppHost instance
    // I guess it should be a class variable to keep AppHost running as long as the factory is alive, i.e. the tests are running
    private DistributedApplication? _app;

    // used by the Dispose pattern
    private bool disposedValue;

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure the WebHostBuilder for the test server. Spins up AppHost and waits for required resources to start.
    /// Obtains the environmental variables from the project (webfrontend) and injects them into the test server.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // local variables
        var environmentVariables = new Dictionary<string, string?>();

        // === Arrange

        // build and configure AppHost (§§)
        var appHost = DistributedApplicationTestingBuilder.CreateAsync<Projects.UnitTestsInAspire_AppHost>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        appHost.Services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(clientBuilder =>
        {
            clientBuilder.AddStandardResilienceHandler();
        });

        // disable port randomization for tests
        // https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/discussions/6843#discussioncomment-11444891
        //appHost.Configuration["DcpPublisher:RandomizePorts"] = "false";

        // build the AppHost synchronously
        _app = appHost.BuildAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


        // start AppHost
        // Note: As far as I understand, the containers are not run in DockerDesktop but in some in-memory thingy
        var resourceNotificationService = _app.Services.GetRequiredService<ResourceNotificationService>();
        _app.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // wait until the required resources are running (§§)
        var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        resourceNotificationService.WaitForResourceAsync("webfrontend", KnownResourceStates.Running).WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        resourceNotificationService.WaitForResourceAsync("PostgresServer", KnownResourceStates.Running).WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Waited {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms for required resources to start");



        // = get env variables from project-under-test

        // find UnitTestsInAspire.Web project in AppHost (§§) (adapted from https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/discussions/878#discussioncomment-9596424)
        var testProject = appHost.Resources.First(r => r.Name == "webfrontend");

        // make sure it is a ProjectResource with an environment and
        // get the annotations marking the methods/fields that contain the environmental variables
        if (testProject is IResourceWithEnvironment &&
            testProject.TryGetEnvironmentVariables(out var annotations))
        {
            // To invoke the callback functions to obtain the environmental variables, an EnvironmentCallbackContext
            // is required, which can be created from a DistributedApplicationExecutionContext, but this requires
            // certain services, that can be obtained from the AppHost's service registry. Thus, hijack the AppHosts services
            // to create the DistributedApplicationExecutionContext.
            var options = new DistributedApplicationExecutionContextOptions(DistributedApplicationOperation.Run)
            {
                ServiceProvider = _app.Services
            };

            var executionContext = new DistributedApplicationExecutionContext(options);
            var environmentCallbackContext = new EnvironmentCallbackContext(executionContext);


            // materialize the environmental variables by calling the callbacks in the environmentCallbackContext
            foreach (var annotation in annotations)
            {
                annotation.Callback(environmentCallbackContext).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }

            // Translate environment variable __ syntax to :
            foreach (var (key, value) in environmentCallbackContext.EnvironmentVariables)
            {
                if (testProject is ProjectResource && key == "ASPNETCORE_URLS") continue;

                var configValue = value switch
                {
                    string val => val,
                    IValueProvider v => v.GetValueAsync().AsTask().Result,
                    null => null,
                    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unsupported value, {value.GetType()}")
                };

                if (configValue is not null)
                {
                    environmentVariables[key.Replace("__", ":")] = configValue;
                }
            }
        }

        // inject the environmental variables into the test server
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, cb) =>
        {
            cb.AddInMemoryCollection(environmentVariables);
        });
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method is part of the recommended dispose pattern. I assume that WebApplicationFactory already implements
    /// <code>public void Dispose()</code>, which calls <code>Dispose(disposing: true)</code>.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // dispose the AppHost
                _app?.Dispose();
            }

            // free unmanaged resources and override finalizer
            // set large fields to null

            // Call the base class's Dispose method to ensure base class resources are disposed of
            base.Dispose(disposing);

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }
}

It spins up the AppHost, waits for all dependencies to become ready, and then copies the environmental variables of the project-under-test inside the DistributedApplicationTestingBuilder to a second instance of the project-under-test built with a WebApplicationFactory that is used for the actual testing. This way, all connection strings and other settings that Aspire manages are available to the test project.
The test class itself looks like this:
/// <summary>
/// Perform functional unit tests on the HistoryService defined in UnitTestsInAspire.Web.
/// The custom WebApplicationFactory spins up the AppHost and injects the environmental variables from the project (webfrontend).
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// In order for the compiler to find the project to test, you need to add <code>public partial class Program { }</code> to
/// <code>Program.cs</code> in the project you want to test.
/// </remarks>
public sealed class FunctionalTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory,
                                    ITestOutputHelper _output) : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    // grants access to the Services defined in UnitTestsInAspire.Web
    // InitializeAsync throws an exception if the scope could not be created, so it is never null when used
    private IServiceScope _scope = null!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the test environment. 
    /// Creates the scope for the UnitTestsInAspire.Web services.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        // === Spinning up AppHost and copying the environmantal variables to UnitTestsInAspire.Web is 
        // done in the custon WebApplicationFactory


        // get ServiceProvider from UnitTestsInAspire.Web (for obtain dependencies from DI)
        // I store the scope as class variable, so that each test can derive it's own service. I think that if all tests were
        // to use the same service and run in parallel, they might interfere with each other (e.g. concurrent DBcontext access)
        _scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();

        if (_scope == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ServiceScope could not be created for UnitTestsInAspire.Web.");
        }


        // development: Verify the configuration within the application
        // Note: The connection string is found in this way, even if the ConnectionStrings:applicationDb is not present in the appsettings.json
        // Surprisingly, the HistoryService does not pick up the connection string, unless at least a dummy string is present in the appsettings.json
        var projectConfig = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        var dbConnectionString = projectConfig.GetConnectionString("applicationDb");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbConnectionString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ConnectionString for applicationDb is missing.");
        }

        // avoid CS1998 Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AddAndRetreiveDataPoint()
    {
        // === Arrange
        // is done in InitializeAsync


        // === Act

        // get Services via dependency injection
        var serviceProvider = _scope.ServiceProvider;
        var HistoryService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HistoryService>();


        // perform some tests and assert ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Disposes the scope for the UniTestsInAspire.Web services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        _scope?.Dispose();

        // avoid CS1998 Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

There are some caveat's to this approach:

To be able to reference Program.cs of the UnitTestsInAspire.Web project, public partial class Program { } has to be added to the Program.cs.

The connection string to the Postgres database can be obtained via GetConnectionString (see CustomWebApplicationFactory.ConfigureWebHost), but strangely, the connection string is not picked up by the HistoryService, unless a dummy string is added to the appsettings.json of the UnitTestsInAspire.Web project?!?

To add the migration and update the database, a workaround described here and here has to be used:

Change to the UnitTestsInAspire.Web directory, then execute dotnet ef migrations add Init --output-dir ./Data/Migrations
Run the App and get the connection string from the environmental variables in AppHost via the Aspire Dashboard (check Details page)
While the app is still running, update the database with dotnet ef database update --no-build --connection "..."



This solution is adapted from here. It uses a cumbersome way to materialize the environmental variables of the project-under-test, maybe there is a more direct way of accessing the environmental variables.
